# How to create a OLAP table in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

This question may sound very rudimentary.

To my surprise, after several hours of searching and referring many books, I could not figure out ...

How to CREATE/MAKE SURE the below table that is created in Postgresql is STORED in Columnar format and is effective for analytical queries. We have 500 million records in this table. We never update this table.

Question is how  can if its a ANALYTICAL/COLUMNAR table vs a transactional table ?

```
CREATE TABLE dwh.access_log 
(
  ts timestamp with time zone, 
  remote_address text,
  remote_user text,
  url text,
  domain text,
  status_code int,
  body_size int,
  http_referer text,
  http_user_agent text
);
```

Thanks

Comment: What happened when you executed this query?

Comment: @FrankHeikens tables get created , I can insert records and query .. Question is how  can I its a ANALYTICAL/COLUMNAR table vs a transactional table

Comment: You can’t because PostgreSQL has a row orientation, like (almost?) all relational databases. However, it can do many/most/all analytics that you need. 500 million rows is not a huge number of records

Comment: If you have a performance problem, then show us your query and the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze)`.

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't have a columnar format, unless you have deployed some extension/fork that implements such.

Comment: ClickHouse has columnar format - it has excellent performance for OLAP and analytics.